# Can I set default value to the function when passing it to a Child component?

Tags: reactjs

`A component` passes `setState` function as a prop to a `child component`.

`B component` doesn't pass `setState` props to a `child component` so when `B component` gets fired I get an error saying `setState is not a function`.

I know if I pass a value I could set it like this `value = ''` which if there is no value, will be an empty string.

Is there a way to set default value? to the function?
Or how can I execute `setState` function when only `A component is fired?

```
const A = () => {
  const setState = () => {
    console.log("A fire");
  };

  return <Child setState={setState} />;
};

const B = () => {
  return <Child />;
};

const Child = ({ setState }) => {
  setState();
  return <diva>hello</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set default value? to the function?

You could either just add a simple condition if `setState` exists:

```
if (setState) {
   setState(); // if setState exists - call it
}
```

or use a *shorthand* syntax with *optional chaining*:

```
setState?.();
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Awesome I will try these two. and you meant `setState?.()` or `setState?()` ?

Comment: @tomo1234 `setState?.()` - it will be called only if `setState` exists.